# A Python dictionary with repeated fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm constructing a dictionary with Python to use with a SOAP API.

My SOAP API takes an input like this:

```
<dataArray>
  <AccountingYearData>
    <Handle>
      <Year>string</Year>
    </Handle>
    <Year>string</Year>
    <FromDate>dateTime</FromDate>
    <ToDate>dateTime</ToDate>
    <IsClosed>boolean</IsClosed>
  </AccountingYearData>
  <AccountingYearData>
    <Handle>
      <Year>string</Year>
    </Handle>
    <Year>string</Year>
    <FromDate>dateTime</FromDate>
    <ToDate>dateTime</ToDate>
    <IsClosed>boolean</IsClosed>
  </AccountingYearData>
</dataArray>
```

Se this for the full string
https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?op=AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray

Notice how the field  appears multiple times.

How can I create a Python dict with this data?

If I do this:

```
data = {
  'dataArray':{
    'AccountingYearData':{
      'Handle':{'Year':'2017'}, 
      'Year':'2017',
      'FromDate':'2017-01-01', 
      'ToDate':'2017-12-31', 
      'IsClosed':'False'
    },
    'AccountingYearData':{
      'Handle':{'Year':'2017'}, 
      'Year':'2017',
      'FromDate':'2017-01-01', 
      'ToDate':'2017-12-31', 
      'IsClosed':'False'
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
>>> type (data)
<type 'dict'>
>>> data {
  'dataArray': {
    'AccountingYearData': {
      'IsClosed': 'False', 
      'FromDate': '2017-01-01', 
      'Handle': {'Year': '2017'}, 
      'ToDate': '2017-12-31', 
      'Year': '2017'
    }
  }
}
```

It's as expected I think, but now what I need.

Comment: Use a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Dictionary keys are **always** unique. Don't use a dictionary, use a list. `data = [{'Handle':{'Year':'2017'}, 'Year':'2017', 'FromDate':'2017-01-01', 'ToDate':'2017-12-31', 'IsClosed':'False'}, {'Handle':{'Year':'2017'}, 'Year':'2017', 'FromDate':'2017-01-01', 'ToDate':'2017-12-31', 'IsClosed':'False'}]` would capture the structure just fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer seems obvious and is even hinted by the "dataArray" name: if you have a list of items, then you want to use a `list` to store them:

```
data = {
    'dataArray':[
        {
            'AccountingYearData':{
                'Handle':{'Year':'2017'}, 
                'Year':'2017',
                'FromDate':'2017-01-01', 
                'ToDate':'2017-12-31', 
                'IsClosed':'False'
                },
            },
        {
            'AccountingYearData':{
                'Handle':{'Year':'2017'}, 
                'Year':'2017',
                'FromDate':'2017-01-01', 
                'ToDate':'2017-12-31', 
                'IsClosed':'False'
                },
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: That make a dict with repeated fields, 
but the API takes the argument dataArray, so I do:

data = [{'AccountingYearData': {...}}, {'AccountingYearData': {...}}]
c.service.AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray(dataArray = data)

But I only send half of the data
Is there a way out of that?

Comment: I have asked this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384363/api-takes-only-half-of-my-list