# API takes only half of my list

Tags: python, api, dictionary

As suggested in this answer [A Python dictionary with repeated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361632) , I'm trying to send a list of dicts to an API with python and the zeep module.

But, the API receive only half of my data.

The API expects a dict and takes the argument dataArray like this:

```
<dataArray>
  <AccountingYearData>
    <Handle>
      <Year>string</Year>
    </Handle>
    <Year>string</Year>
    <FromDate>dateTime</FromDate>
    <ToDate>dateTime</ToDate>
    <IsClosed>boolean</IsClosed>
  </AccountingYearData>
  <AccountingYearData>
    <Handle>
      <Year>string</Year>
    </Handle>
    <Year>string</Year>
    <FromDate>dateTime</FromDate>
    <ToDate>dateTime</ToDate>
    <IsClosed>boolean</IsClosed>
  </AccountingYearData>
</dataArray>
```

Se this link for the full string https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?op=AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray

So I do like this:

```
data = [
    {
        'AccountingYearData':{
            'Handle':{'Year':'2018'}, 
            'Year':'2018',
            'FromDate':'2018-01-01', 
            'ToDate':'2018-12-31', 
            'IsClosed':'False'
            },
        },
    {
        'AccountingYearData':{
            'Handle':{'Year':'2019'}, 
            'Year':'2019',
            'FromDate':'2019-01-01', 
            'ToDate':'2019-12-31', 
            'IsClosed':'False'
            },
        },
    ]

c.service.AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray(dataArray = data)
```

But with this the API only gets half of the data.

Inserting the list into a dict like this:

```
data = {
    'dataArray': {
        [
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    }
}

c.service.AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray(data)
```

Is not accepted by the API.

Is there a way out of that?

Best Regards
Kresten

EDIT:

My full code is this:

```
from zeep import Client
import datetime

AppSecretToken = 'xxxx'
AgreementGrantToken = 'xxxx'

c = Client("https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?WSDL")
c.service.ConnectWithToken(token=AgreementGrantToken, appToken=AppSecretToken)

data = [\
    {'AccountingYearData': {\
        'Handle': {'Year': '2018'},\
        'Year': '2018',\
        'FromDate': datetime.date(2018,1,1),\
        'ToDate': datetime.date(2018,12,31), \
        'IsClosed': False }\
    }, \
    {'AccountingYearData': {\
        'Handle': {'Year': '2019'},\
        'Year': '2019',\
        'FromDate': datetime.date(2019,1,1),\
        'ToDate': datetime.date(2019,12,31), \
        'IsClosed': False }\
    } \
]\

print(c.service.AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray(dataArray = data))

data = {'dataArray': \
[\
    {'AccountingYearData': {\
        'Handle': {'Year': '2018'},\
        'Year': '2018',\
        'FromDate': datetime.date(2018,1,1),\
        'ToDate': datetime.date(2018,12,31), \
        'IsClosed': False }\
    }, \
    {'AccountingYearData': {\
        'Handle': {'Year': '2019'},\
        'Year': '2019',\
        'FromDate': datetime.date(2019,1,1),\
        'ToDate': datetime.date(2019,12,31), \
        'IsClosed': False }\
    } \
]\
}

print(c.service.AccountingYear_CreateFromDataArray(data))
```

Response:

```
[{
    'Year': '2018'
}]
None
```

Comment: Dude paste your complete code only then the problem will be detected

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Please find the code in the question.

Comment: Any chance the handles have to be unique? For instance, what happens if you change `'Handle': {'Year': '2018'}` to `'Handle': {'Year': '2019'}` in the second dictionary and change the `FromDate` and `ToDate` accordingly?

Comment: That is a typo only here, in my code it is 2018 and 2019. I'll correct it in the question. Sorry.

Comment: OK, @Kresten, that's not it then. I would try checking what your code is actually sending to the server by using tcpdump or Wireshark. You could also try sending the requests semi-manually using something like curl but then you'll first have to authenticate as described [here](https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/economicwebservice.asmx?op=ConnectWithToken), save the cookie/token and reuse it in all subsequent requests.

Comment: I found a way to get inspect what is send and received by the zeep module.
It was right there in the documentation http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html#debugging